# Android Power-Off dialog not showing

Tags: android, root

I rooted china android phone and deleted applications which contained ads and Chinese language named. Phone is running good but when I hold the power button, the power off dialog does not appear and phone shuts down without showing the shutdown animation and restarts. Both the shut down and boot animations are present in `/system/media` directory.

I am unable to find after Googling that which application I deleted from the phone by which this is all happening.

Need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search on Google play, find restarting application. Choose one and install it. Root your phone and move the application to the `system/app` folder. `unroot` your phone and you are now good to go.